# Error While creating Java Binding Library in Xamarin (Twilio)

Tags: xamarin, jar, xamarin.android

Hello i have the errors when try create binding.

```
Com.Twilio.Ipmessaging.IPMessagingClientListener.cs(45,45): Error CS0102: The type `Com.Twilio.Ipmessaging.ErrorEventArgs' already contains a definition for `p0' (CS0102) (TwilioJarBinding)
Com.Twilio.Ipmessaging.IPMessagingClientListener.cs(52,52): Error CS0102: The type `Com.Twilio.Ipmessaging.ErrorEventArgs' already contains a definition for `P0' (CS0102) (TwilioJarBinding)
```

I tried to fix in Metadata.xml

```xml
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.twilio.ipmessaging']/class[@name='ErrorEventArgs']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName"> p1 </attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.twilio.ipmessaging']/class[@name='ErrorEventArgs']/field[@name='P0']" name="managedName"> P1 </attr>
```

but it's not helped

code:

```cs
public partial class ErrorEventArgs : global::System.EventArgs {

    public ErrorEventArgs (global::Com.Twilio.Ipmessaging.IErrorInfo p0)
    {
        this.p0 = p0;
    }

    global::Com.Twilio.Ipmessaging.IErrorInfo p0; // error!
    public global::Com.Twilio.Ipmessaging.IErrorInfo P0 { // error
        get { return p0; }
    }
}
```